# Uploading a file and I can't get past the 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith' error

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error

```
AttributeError at /admin/user/usermodel/1/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

when I try and up load a file to the admin, I am really new to file uploading and can't figure it out

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/project/foo/yesno/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/user/project/foo/yesno/static_store',
)

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/project/foo/yesno/static/media',

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

filename = ''

# Create your models here.

class UserModel(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User)
    position    = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    thumbnail   = models.FileField(upload_to="uploaded_files", blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class ThumbnailForm(forms.Form):

    thumbnail = forms.FileField()
```

views.py

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

def UploadPicRequest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        thumb_form = ThumbnailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if thumb_form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            thumb_form = ThumbnailForm()
        return render_to_response('/update_profile/error.html', {'thumb_form': thumb_form})
```

Comment: My guess is the , at the end of MEDIA_ROOT

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/project/foo/yesno/static/media',
```

defines `MEDIA_ROOT` as a tuple.  Specifically, it makes it a one-item tuple, due to the trailing comma: tuples are defined by commas, not as is commonly believed by parentheses (except the empty tuple:-).

Remove that probably-unintended trailing comma and this particular error should go away.